# Prove: $\frac{1}{1*2} + \frac{1}{2*3} + \frac{1}{3*4} +⋯+ \frac{1}{n(n+1)}= \frac{n}{(n+1)}$

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I was working on my proof by induction and I'm second guessing myself on solving the left hand side.

> Prove: $$ \frac{1}{1\times 2}+\frac{1}{2 \times 3}+ \frac{1}{3 \times 4}+ \ldots + \frac{1}{n\times(n+1) }= \frac{n}{n+1}  \qquad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $$

**Proof: Principle of Mathmatical Induction (P.M.I.)**

Assume: P(n):1/(1*2)+1/(2*3)+1/(3*4)+⋯+1/(n*(n+1) )=n/(n+1),∀n∈N

First we need to show that P(1)  is true.

P(1):1/((1)*((1)+1) )=((1))/((1)+1)

P(1):1/2=1/2

∴ P(1)  is true.

Next,assume P(k)  is true for some k∈N.

P(k):  1/(1*2)+1/(2*3)+1/(3*4)+⋯+1/(k*(k+1) )=k/(k+1),is true.

Show P(k+1)  is true.

P(k+1):  1/(1*2)+1/(2*3)+1/(3*4)+⋯+1/(k*(k+2) )=k/(k+2),for some k∈N

L.H.S.= 1/(1*2)+1/(2*3)+1/(3*4)+⋯+1/(k*(k+2) )

= [1/(1*2)+1/(2*3)+1/(3*4)+⋯+1/(k*(k+1) )]+1/(k*(k+2) )

= k/(k+1)+1/(k*(k+2) )

= k/(k+1)+1/(k^2+2k)

=0/1+1/(k^2+2k)

= k/(k+2)

= R.H.S.

∴ P(k+1)  is true.

Hence,by P.M.I.

P(n) is true for all n∈N.∎

Comment: You might find this MathJax tutorial worthwhile for making your work ... well, readable. Plus its use is generally preferred on this site. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: It can be thought of as this: $$\frac{1}{1*2}+\frac{1}{2*3}+\frac{1}{3*4}+...+\frac{1}{n(n+1)}$$
$$=\frac{0!}{2!}+\frac{1!}{3!}+\frac{2!}{4!}+...+\frac{(n-1)!}{(n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 5):

For $P(k+1)$ the denominator should be $(k+1)(k+2)$, not $k(k+1)$, so we need to show that $$\frac{1}{1\times 2}+\frac{1}{2 \times 3}+ \frac{1}{3 \times 4}+ \ldots + \frac1{k\times(k+1)}+\frac{1}{(k+1)\times(k+2) }= \frac{k+1}{k+2}$$ where $n$ is replaced by $k+1$. From the induction hypothesis, it is sufficient to show that \begin{align}\frac k{k+1}+\frac{1}{(k+1)\times(k+2) }= \frac{k+1}{k+2}&\impliedby k(k+2)+1=\frac{k+1}{k+2}\times(k+1)(k+2)\\&\impliedby k^2+2k+1=(k+1)^2\end{align} which is true as $k>0$.